# Loop Table using distance = speed * time

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

The distance a vehicle travels can be calculated as follows:

distance = speed * time

Write a program that asks the user for the speed of a vehicle (in miles per hour) and how many hours it has traveled. The program should then use a loop to display the distance the vehicle has traveled for each hour of that time period. Here is an example of the output:

What is the speed of the vehicle in mph? 40

How many hours has it traveled? 3

Hour    Distance Traveled

---

1      :      40

2      :      80

3      :     120

I've gotten everything done so far but can't manage to get the table to come out properly, as shown in the example table at the first hour (1) it should start at 40 but instead it starts at 120. Can someone help me fix the code? forgot to mention it should work for any value the user enters such as if someone was going 50 mph in 5 hours

```
g = 'y'
while g == 'Y' or g == 'y':
    speed = int(input('Enter mph: '))
    time = int(input('Enter hours: '))

    if time <= 0 or speed <= 0:
        print('Invalid Hours and mph must be greater than 0')
    else:
        for t in range(time):
            distance = speed * time

            print(t + 1,':', distance)
            time = time * 2


        g = 'n'
print('End')
```

Comment: Just step through your code in your head.  Where does it first go wrong?  It's easy because it goes wrong in the very first calculation that it does!  Which calculation is that?  Why is it wrong?

Comment: another clue, what are you multiplying by to get distance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change 2 things in your program. **First**, there's no need to double the time inside for loop, **Second** use variable **t** instead of **time** to calculate distance.

```
g = 'y'
while g == 'Y' or g == 'y':
speed = int(input('Enter mph: '))
time = int(input('Enter hours: '))

if time <= 0 or speed <= 0:
    print('Invalid Hours and mph must be greater than 0')
else:
    for t in range(time):
        distance = speed * (t+1)        // Use t+1 instead of time

        print(t + 1,':', distance)
        # time = time * 2              // No need to double the time


    g = 'n'
print('End')

Input: 
40
3

Output:
(1, ':', 40)
(2, ':', 80)
(3, ':', 120)
End
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the commas from the print line, and print out the numbers in string format and concat it to the string colon like:

```
        print(str(t + 1) + ':' + str(distance))
```

You also need to increment the time by one not multiply by 2

```
        time = time + 1
```

Your output distance also can be fixed by calculating it based on t instead of time

```
        distance = speed * (t+1)
```